# How to cast an int to a float in OpenCL?

Tags: java, casting, int, opencl

I am writing a mandelbrot fractal renderer in Java using OpenCL. In my kernel code I need to cast an `int` to a `float`. But when I say `printf("%d", sizeX, "\n%d", (float) sizeX, "\n\n");` (`sizeX` is an int), I get the following result in the console:

```
512
0
```

And indeed, `sizeX` should be 512, but in order to do further calculations, I need it to be a floating point number. Does someone know why it always turns into a 0 when I try to cast it?

EDIT:
I also tried to convert it by doing `float fSizeX = 0.0f + sizeX` but that didn't work too.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code which doesn't work?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I have a function to convert an integer to a float4 for more precision `inline float4 qfAssignInt(int value)
{
    return (float4)((float) value, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code does not produce the given result. The output would be `512` without anything else.

The `printf()` method (and the `format()` method, too) has only one "format specifying" argument. You might want to try something like this:

```
printf("%d\n%f\n\n", sizeX, (float) sizeX);
```

Also the `%d` format specifier will throw an `InvaligArgumentException` on a non `int`/`Integer` value, so i used `%f` instead.